# Un-Install OS Patch (KBs) in Physical PRODUCTION Servers - Consequences

Tags: sql-server, windows-server, patching

We have our PRODUCTION Database and Application Servers which are Physical Servers .

Recently , the October month OS Patches (specific KBs) are little problematic and reported by Microsoft too that they are going to fix in November patches .

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dataaccesstechnologies/2017/10/18/unexpected-error-from-external-database-driver-1-microsoft-jet-database-engine-after-applying-october-security-updates/

The document says :

Uninstall the security patch (Not recommended):
Registry change (Not recommended): [Request you to take a backup of the registry key before making any changes]
Please guide me on :

Do I need to expect any issue while Uninstalling patches (specific KBs).

Since my servers being PRODUCTION and Physical in nature , what are the consequences I might face while rollback of patches .

In this case is it recommended to Rollback patches ?

I am preparing one PowerShell code for this process .
Kindly help .

Comment: There is no way for anyone to know as we don't know what might be running on the server that uses any of the components affected by these patches.  The best approach is to test it on an identical server.  I don't know when it was updated, but the page indicates that a fix has been released for this issue.

Answer (score 2):

As the MSDN page you link to states that a fix has already been released, I would install that rather than removing the previous update as the fix is likely to be intended to go over the top (though is likely to be made such that it can replace the older update too) and it will only be one operation rather than two potentially requiring two reboots.

In either case the main consequence of adding or removing patches is the potential need to reboot (or if not a full reboot, restart affected services) which may involve downtime depending on your arrangement (a cluster might be able to avoid downtime). The extra consequence of removing patches (without installing a replacement) is that the changes within them are gone, which if it is a roll-up patch could mean unrelated security updates that you need to mitigate by other means until the patch can be re-applied.

The best approach to take is to test in a production-like environment before making changes to production proper.

Comment: Thanks @Dave for the hints , I will give a try in Stage before PROD